# How can I get ALL addresses within a polygon, with Google Maps or another free provider?

Tags: polygon, maps, google

I am hoping to find a good solution to doing this.

We would like to be able to define a polygon of latitude/longitude values and be able to have a dataset of all of the addresses within that polygon.

Using a free service for this would be ideal, like Google Maps.

The polygons can be the size of several zip codes and will change depending on the dataset attached to it.

Please let me know if you know how I can do this.

Comment: How big is the polygon? which country?

Comment: The polygons can be the size of several zip codes, in several different countries, but starting the Germany to begin with.